# Interfaz Gráfica y Eventos de Foco

Tags: java

Necesito ayuda. Estoy haciendo un curso de Java, estoy en la parte de interfaces gráficas y eventos de foco.

El profesor nos ha pedido que hiciéramos una interfaz gráfica sencilla que contenga 3 JLabel y 3 JTextField, esa parte la echo correctamente.
El tema es que nos ha pedido que el programa al escribir la contraseña cuando se pierde el foco detecte si la contraseña tiene más de 5 caracteres y si tiene menos de 5 caracteres que nos imprima en consola un mensaje “Contraseña poco segura”.
Y en el caso del email nos ha pedido que al escribir una dirección de email si es válida no ocurra nada, pero si la dirección de email no es válida que nos imprima un mensaje en consola “Dirección de email no es válida”.

Les dejo el código que he echo:

```
package Eventos;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.*;
public class EventoFocoEjercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MarcoFoco miFoco=new MarcoFoco();

    }

}

class MarcoFoco extends JFrame {

    public MarcoFoco() {

        setBounds(200,100, 600,450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        add(new LaminaFocos());
    }
}

class LaminaFocos extends JPanel{

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        usuario=new JTextField();
        contraseña=new JTextField();
        email=new JTextField();

        lblUsuario=new JLabel("Usuario");
        lblContraseña=new JLabel("Contraseña");
        lblEmail=new JLabel("Email");

        usuario.setBounds(220, 30, 150, 20);
        contraseña.setBounds(220, 70, 150, 20);
        email.setBounds(220, 110, 150, 20);

        lblUsuario.setBounds(100, 30, 150, 20);
        lblContraseña.setBounds(100, 70, 150, 20);
        lblEmail.setBounds(100, 110, 150, 20);

        add(usuario);
        add(contraseña);
        add(email);

        add(lblUsuario);
        add(lblContraseña);
        add(lblEmail);

        EventoDeFoco foco=new EventoDeFoco();
        usuario.addFocusListener(foco);
        contraseña.addFocusListener(foco);
        email.addFocusListener(foco);
    }


    private class EventoDeFoco implements FocusListener {


        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }

    private JTextField usuario, contraseña, email;
    private JLabel lblUsuario, lblContraseña, lblEmail;

}
```

Sinceramente me he nublado y no lo puedo resolver, se que es sencillo pero no puedo.
Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pues en el método focusLost tendrás que poner las comprobaciones. Sería algo así:

```
if(contraseña.length()<5){
   System.out.println("Error contraseña menor que 5");
}
if(!email.contains("@")){
   System.out.println("Error, escribe una direccion valida");
}
```